# How to Update Group Devices shadow at once using AWS IoT Groups?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I have a UI where I have Room as IoT group and room is having number of devices. I want to add a toggle on individual devices as well as on Rooms. Updating all devices shadow at once by room. Is it achievable using AWS IoT Groups ??

Comment: [THIS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/API_UpdateThingShadow.html) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

> [Jobs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-jobs.html) - AWS IoT jobs can be used to define a set of remote
>   operations that are sent to and executed on one or more devices
>   connected to AWS IoT.

Example - you can define a job that instructs a set of devices to download and install application or firmware updates, reboot, rotate certificates, or perform remote troubleshooting operations.

To use Jobs or Messages is up to your requirements. If you want to update a set of devices Jobs seems to do the work, or its just one device message will do.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go through greengrass route which would be much more easier and would help with granular control of devices.

- Please check this on the topic [Interacting with Devices in an AWS Greengrass Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/module4.html).
- If you are able to achieve it with manual steps then you can build the application using Lambda with IoT Rules as well for your toggle scenarios.
- Look at the [limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/thing-groups.html) of using the thing group for better understanding.